# Issue: Image hiding behind PDF element while embedding through Apache pdfbox library

Tags: java, image, pdf, background, pdfbox

I am using apache pdfbox jar to embed image to attached PDF with below JAVA code:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.MemoryUsageSetting;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.JPEGFactory;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class importImageToPDF1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PDDocument pdDocument = null;
        try {
            String sourceFilePath = "D:\\files\\sourceFile.pdf";
            String destinationFilePath = "D:\\files\\outputFile.pdf";
            String imagePath = "D:\\files\\image.png";

            pdDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(sourceFilePath), MemoryUsageSetting.setupTempFileOnly());
            pdDocument.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);

            PDPage pdPage = pdDocument.getPage(0);

            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(imagePath));
            PDPageContentStream pageContentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, pdPage, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
            pageContentStream.saveGraphicsState();

            PDImageXObject image = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(pdDocument, bufferedImage);

            pageContentStream.drawImage(image, 10, 730, 100, 100);
            pageContentStream.restoreGraphicsState();
            pageContentStream.close();
            pdDocument.save(new File(destinationFilePath));
            pdDocument.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (pdDocument != null) {
                pdDocument.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is link for source PDF:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gP1EIso0Ww4sw-cliVVEb_YI6cys2kEj?usp=sharing

with this code image embedded in background and hide behind specific element. Embedded image should be in foreground of pdf. that means image should be viewed properly.

I want image to be display in foreground above all the elements in PDF.

Note: Image getting viewed properly after embedding in other PDFs, only having issue with attached pdf.

Comment: Your content is really two stamp annotations, and these are on top AFAIK.

Comment: Indeed, the static content of the page in your original PDF is a single space character. The tables you see are bitmap images overlaying the static content as appearances of stamp annotations. If you want your image to cover even page annotations, add it in a new annotation at the end of the annotation list of the page.